# Can a newly created vampire learn to cast spells?

Tags: magic, shadowrun-sr5

I have a player who was previously mundane and just became infected with vampirism. The character now has a Magic attribute of 1, and they want to learn spellcasting and spells. Part of me thinks that this should not be allowed, but I'm not sure if I'm right.

Since the character now has a Magic attribute, can they cast spells? If they can or can't, a rules reference would be helpful so that I have a evidence if I have to break their heart.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They gain only limited magical abilities:

*Run Faster*, p. 141, emphasis mine:

> All Infected are dual natured and may freely learn the
>   *Assensing* and *Astral Combat* skills. **Unless they’re magically
>   active, however, they cannot learn or use skills linked
>   to the Magic attribute. Neither can they astrally project,
>   bond foci, or initiate.** An exception to this is given by the
>   Magical Guard power, which enables the Infected character
>   who has it to learn the *Counterspelling* skill.

(*Magical guard* is described in *Street Grimoire* (power description) and *Run Faster* (Karma cost))

Since you can't default magic skills, that means no spells for the <strike>wicked</strike> infected.

So the character gains the ability to astraly preceive, can learn to interpret his/her observations and defend him/herself against attackers from the astral plane and could learn to counterspell, if (s)he takes the appropriate positive quality, but can't learn to cast spells or rituals or summon spirits and can't even use a *weapon focus*.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**. As stated in the p.142 of the core rulebook, emphasis mine:

> **Magical skills**
>
> Magic skills are reserved for those who practice magic.
> In order to acquire magic-specific skills, characters must have a
> quality that provides a Magic rating. In order to use these skills,
> that ***Magic rating must be 1 or higher***. Please visit Magic, p. 276, for
> all your Magical skill-using needs.

And the spellcasting skill, which is required to cast spells, is into this category, and all the others of course, so yes but he now needs to start buying this skills and spells with karma

This is based only on the core rulebook as it seems that other suplements may treat about this specifically.

Comment: I think this general rule is overridden by the specific rule found by [Fabien](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/59686/2788).

Comment: Maybe, I only have Core Rulebook, answered from that perspective =(

Comment: However I don't like to limit characters, a character that starts as a commoner and gains his magic through play is a cool idea. Life is what happens while you plan doing other things, so it could be an unexpected turn in his life!

Comment: Both valid points. If you like to play it that way, there's nothing wrong with it, just pointing it out to anyone who gets confused between the two conflicting answers.

Comment: @CorvenDallas I suggest you edit your answer to make it clear that this is based on core-only, and to include your reasoning for preferring this over the more specific rule found by fabian.